# nil can't be coerced into Fixnum, adding a number to a image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add a number to an image through a click action, but when I execute the action I get an

> nil can't be coerced into Fixnum

in

```
app/controllers/competitions_controller.rb:30:in `-'
app/controllers/competitions_controller.rb:30:in `block in submit_vote'
app/controllers/competitions_controller.rb:29:in `submit_vote'
```

The action,

```
def submit_vote
  total = (@competition.pictures.count + 1)
  @competition.pictures.each do |picture|
    picture.points = (picture.points + (total - picture.position))
    picture.save!
  end
  redirect_to competition_path(@competition), notice: "Je hebt gestemd"
end
```

I think I might have to do something with the fact that the value of points and position is "nill" when I do `Picture.all` in the Rails console.

I've tried adding a default number to those values but it doesn't seem to help,

```
class AddPointsToPictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pictures, :points, default: 0, :integer
  end
end
```

It still says points "nill" instead of the expected "0" in the rails console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define default value if it is nil

```
...
  @competition.pictures.each do |picture|
    picture.points = ((picture.points || 0) + (total - (picture.position || 0)))
    picture.save!
  end
...
```

Comment: You can also just call .to_i on the properties. Since nil.to_i => 0

Answer (score 2):

Just going to add my answer, as I personally dislike the whole (x || y) approach:

```
def submit_vote
   total = (@competition.pictures.count + 1)
   @competition.pictures.each do |picture|
      picture.points = (picture.points.to_i + (total.to_i - picture.position.to_i))
      picture.save!   
   end

   redirect_to competition_path(@competition), notice: "Je hebt gestemd"
end
```

You can simply add **.to_i** on the parameters you use, as Rails will convert **nil.to_i** into 0:

```
c700595-3:VtM deh0002a$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.8) 2.1.3 
:001 > nil.to_i
  => 0
```